# How to move deleted HDFS file into the Previous location

Tags: hdfs

This is the path when I have deleted the fie from the existing folder
Moved: 'hdfs://nameservice1/user/edureka_978336/Assignment24/abc.txt' to trash at: hdfs://nameservice1/
user/edureka_978336/.Trash/Current/user/edureka_978336/Assignment24/abc.txt

Where Im trying to restore it through MV function but it's not working

hdfs dfs -mv /user/edureka_978336/.Trash/Current/user/edureka_978336/Assignment24/abc.txt/user/edureka_978336/Asign
ment24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you paste the error which is coming when you say it's not working.

```
hdfs dfs -mv sourcePath targetPath
```

This command should work for moving the file back from trash. Make sure you have permission to pull the data from trash. Can try running with sudo :

```
sudo -u <user.name> hdfs dfs -mv sourcePath targetPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the move should work, if all your paths are correct.

But the important thing is, for how much time the files are retained in Trash.

This value is configured in **core-site.xml** as shown below.

```
<property>
   <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
   <value>30</value>
</property>
```

The value is in minutes and the files will be permanently deleted, after the specified time.

More details about restoring the file here. Take a look.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/recovering-deleted-hdfs-files-cloudera-certified-developer-hadoop-/